# How to apply K-fold cross validation when using model.fit_generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, keras

How to apply K-fold cross validation when using model.fit_generator. i am giving both training and validation data to my network. I aware with the use of sklearn.model_selection.Kfold from [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html), but don't know how to apply to my model. some blocks of my model are:

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('train',  
        target_size=(50, 50),  batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary',color_mode='grayscale')  

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('test',
        target_size=(50, 50),batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary',color_mode='grayscale')

model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,steps_per_epoch=250 ,epochs=40,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=21 )
```